# How can I display [hh]:mm formatted data from an Excel sheet in Power Apps?

Tags: excel, powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula

I have an excel sheet which i've linked to Power Apps. The data in the excel sheet is in the [hh]:mm format.

What do I have to do to get the data to display in the same format in the app.

Pictures for reference

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iH0YL.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5RRV.png)

I've tried using the text function - Text(DataSource.ColumnName, "[$-en-US][hh]:mm") this didnt work

Answer (score 0):

You have a lack of detail in your question, but *if* I understand what you're asking for, my answer is to either

1. change the data type in power query to a duration and see if it automatically adjusts. I doubt it, though. Durations of 25 hours display as ”1.01:00:00” when what your question asks for is "25:00”. So, failing that,
2. Somehow turn your values into fractions of days (e.g. `0.75` represents `18:00`) and convert that to text as appropriate with a custom function such as creating a query called fDaysToHHMM with code like

```js
(days as number) as text =>
let
  hours = 24 * days,
  hoursInt = Number.RoundTowardZero(hours),
  minutesInt = Number.Round(
    60 * (hours - hoursInt)
  ),
  hoursTxt = Text.From(hoursInt),
  minutesTxt = Text.End(
    "0" & Text.From(minutesInt),
    2
  ),
  txt = hoursTxt & ":" & minutesTxt
in
  txt
```